# Backup a hard drive and keep hardlinks in win10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-backup, hardlink

I have 2 hard drives. Drive D used 802GB.

C:  119GB Crucial_CT128MX100SSD1 (SATA (SSD))
D:  931GB Seagate ST1000DM010-2EP102 (SATA )
Mother board: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. GA-73PVM-S2H (Socket 775)

I want to copy Drive D to a new 1TB hard drive but it has a lot of hardlinks.
How can I copy it and keep the hardlinks as well as softlinks?